# Excel4Mac - can't find my VBA modules?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, vba

I have an Excel sheet with several macros, coded on a Windows machine. I used to keep the file in a dropbox folder for easy sharing with my home computer, which is a mac.

I never had any problem until now. The VBA modules of the original file appear to be corrupted so when I try to open the sheet on my windows computer, I get an error message and then Excel proceeds to delete the macros. I changed the xlsm file to zip and tried to recover the binary file, but when I try to read it with wordpad, word, hexreaders etc. it's just a bunch of messed up code.

On Mac instead it works perfectly fine. Well, not really. When I open the file, Excel for Mac asks me if I want to activate the macros. I click yes and the sheet opens fine. Some of these macros are associated to shapes, so to have a "button" effect. When I click one of these shapes, the macro associated to it runs just fine, as always, without crashing. However, I can't see any macro in the macro pane nor in VBA editor. Other info: I already set the security options to minimum. One of these macros has bugs. If I click the debug button on Excel for Mac after running it, the program crashes.

Other content of this sheet is unscathed.

What should I do to recover the body text of these macros either on Windows or Mac? I'm at my wits end. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2007 pro for mac on mac and 2007 pro for windows on windows, problem solved though

Comment: The latest versions of Office for Mac are 2011, 2008, and 2004. There is no Excel 2007 for Mac. If you were talking about Office for Mac 2008, that one does not support Visual Basic for Applications.